# PhpMyAdmin tamanho do arquivo de Import

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou tendo problemas para importar um arquivo .sql de 600mb.

Meu PHP já está autorizado á receber arquivos deste tamanho:

```
memory_limit =1000M
post_max_size = 1000M
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
max_execution_time = 30000
max_input_time = 30000
```

mas ainda sim no PhpMyAdmin o limite é 128mb:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tento fazer o import ele me resulta no seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não entendo porque isso acontece, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você reiniciou o servidor web depois de mudar o arquivo?

Comment: Sim, diversas vezes.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que você faça o `import` do banco, acessando o mysql pelo prompt de comando, é muito mais rápido e você não terá problemas com o tamanho do seu arquivo e não precisará alterar as configurações do seu PHP.

Exemplo:

```
mysql -u username -p nome_banco < nome_do_arquivo.sql
```